# getting error org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:

Tags: java, spring

```
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PNLResultDAOImpl' defined in file [C:\EclipseWS1\SpringJDBCExample\target\classes\com\synechron\tom\pnl\dao\impl\PNLResultDAOImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.synechron.tom.pnl.dao.impl.PNLResultDAOImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.synechron.tom.pnl.dao.impl.PNLResultDAOImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
```

Can you help me to know why this error occurred?

Comment: Add some code from `PNLResultDAOImpl`. As @Jigar pointed out something wrong with its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.synechron.tom.pnl.dao.impl.PNLResultDAOImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Check your constructor for class `com.synechron.tom.pnl.dao.impl.PNLResultDAOImpl` , it throws NullPointerException so spring is unable to initialize that bean

Comment: ya got the error: pnlBucketDTDIndex = pnlBucketDAO.find(pnlBucket); but i have created pnlBucketDAO object using @autowired and also have getter and setter for it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default constructor in PNLResultDAOImpl class and from that you are calling the pnlBucketDAO.find(pnlBucket) method then you can use @Qualifier in the default constructor to inject the bean for pnlBucketDAO.

For ex.

```
@Autowired(required = true)
public PNLResultDAOImpl(@Qualifier("pnlBucketDAO") BasketBallGameModel model) {
       pnlBucketDTDIndex = pnlBucketDAO.find(pnlBucket);
}
```